# How to measure current on an electrolytic etcher

Tags: multimeter, amperage, etching

I'm building a simple electrolytic etcher to mark steel parts. The set up is a 12v DC 5 amp power supply with the ground connected to on side of the steel part and the positive connected to a brass lug with and insulated handle. The lug is covered in a felt pad saturated with an electrolytic solution (salt water) and then pressed against the steel part. The idea is this will etch the metal part to create a mark. I'm not getting good results and I want to check how much current is being delivered through the lug. When I try to set up a multi meter to measure amps I get a small spark and freak the meter out. How can a measure the current at the lug?

Comment: use resistive current limiting  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILPQDXV_Rf0

Comment: In what way are the results not good? You could edit your question to include a photo.

Comment: That's the technique I'm looking for, but the DC version where it etches down into the metal, not blackening. What makes it 'resistive'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the meter in series with the lug.

If you're getting a spark, it sounds like you're connecting the meter across the power supply, which is not the way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I'm being a bonehead and had the meter hooked up incorrectly. When doing it properly I get 7.5a and some other issues.  I'll look into it further and post a separate question. thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take short measurements using your multi-meter in series is fine. However your meter probably has a maximum amount of time indicated in its manual for higher loads before the fuse will blow.

Another way is to get a matching shunt resistor and ammeter. A shunt resistor is a calibrated low ohm resistor designed to have the same resistance over a wide range of temperatures, and the matching ammeter reads the voltage drop over the resistor to display the current flowing. This will allow for a permanent display.

[image: Shunt resistor and ammeter]